# Splitting string when using "which" to subset a data frame

Tags: r

Struggling with a fairly simple issue.

I need to split a string of characters for a single column within a row of a data frame. For example:

```
row    value1                                               value2
state     "AL","AR","AZ","CA","CO","CT","DC","DE","Fl","FL"   0.0307,0.7164,0.1564,0.0503,0.0174,0.0065,0.0111,0.0079,0.0016,0.0016
```

When I use `unlist` I am getting extra characters including escapes (`\`:

CODE: `unlist(strsplit(as.character(df[ which(df$row=='state'),2 ]),'"",""'))`
OUTPUT:  `"\"AL\",\"AR\",\"AZ\",\"CA\",\"CO\",\"CT\",\"DC\",\"DE\",\"Fl\",\"FL\"`

How can I write the code so that the output is just a list of the strings not including the `"\"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to strip the quotes before using `strsplit`, eg

```
s <- gsub('\"', '', as.character(df[which(df$row == 'state'), 2])
strsplit(s, ',')[[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this `strsplit` alone

```
lapply(strsplit(str1, '[",]'), setdiff, "")[[1]]
#[1] "AL" "AR" "AZ" "CA" "CO" "CT" "DC" "DE" "Fl" "FL"
```

---

Or use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(str1, "[A-Z]+")[[1]]
#[1] "AL" "AR" "AZ" "CA" "CO" "CT" "DC" "DE" "F"  "FL"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- '"AL","AR","AZ","CA","CO","CT","DC","DE","Fl","FL"'
```